# Can i launch a prerequisite as an admin on windows?

Tags: vb.net, installation, wix, bootstrapping, dotnetinstaller

Im trying to create a per user installation for my program made in vb.net

I have .net 4 as a prerequisite which im going to download if its not installed

The problem ive run into is admin rights is there a way to install the framework as an admin/elevated user then install my application as the current user so basically

user launches bootstrapper -> pre-reqs run as admin -> application runs as current posibbly limted user.

Im making the installer for my application using Wix (3.5), then im using dotNetInstaller to bootstrap and deal with the prerequisites.

If an admin installs application from the limited users profile he takes over the installation, which is what I dont want, but if the .net isnt installed the admin has to do this.

The admin could install the pre-requesites then close the bootstrapper then the user could install the application but this doesnt seem like a great idea.

Appreciate any help/advice anyone can give.

Answer (score 3):

I think if dotNetInstaller is run un-elevated, and you will start a pre-req which needs elevation, it will automatically show a UAC prompt. But the dotNetInstaller will remain un-elevated. So your installer will also run un-elevated.

See also [Configuring dotNetInstaler 2.0 to install custom prerequisites and then run a custom exe with elevated privileges](http://geekswithblogs.net/JaydPage/archive/2011/03/31/configuring-dotnetinstaler-2.0-to-install-custom-prerequisites-and-then-run.aspx) which explains how to run dotNetInstaller un-elevated.